# Domain Authority and Page Authority staying on 1

Tags: seo, backlinks, ranking, tools, metrics

For some reason, my DA and PA of my website (https://codetheweb.blog) are 1, according to:

- http://www.seoreviewtools.com/website-authority-checker/
- http://www.checkmoz.com/moz-metrics/

When I try looking at my website using the [Moz Open Site Explorer](https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/), it just keeps saying "Loading" forever. Is there something wrong with my site? Is there something wrong with Moz?

I know that my DA & PA cannot actually be 1, for the following reasons:

- I have a few good-quality backlinks according to http://www.seoreviewtools.com/valuable-backlinks-checker/
- My website comes second in Google when searching for "Code The Web" in most countries, whereas it didn't a few weeks ago. However, the PA / DA has not improved since then.

Any idea what is going on? I'm seriously confused. (btw: my URL age is 0.2 years, but surely my DA & PA would at least be more than one... )

Comment: "My website comes second in Google when searching for "Code The Web"" - Although that would seem to be an exact match for your domain name (which returns your _home page_ in the SERPs). This isn't necessarily representative of how well your site ranks for specific keywords relating to your articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by WayBack Machine, your site has existed since around September this year — so around 3 months. A cursory look at your backlink profile in Majestic doesn't suggest any high quality links – quite the opposite.

I can't see any reason why you expect higher values for Page and Domain Authority.

As to why Moz itself isn't showing data, in my experience even for very well-established sites Moz's sample size is substantially smaller than those of more specialised link tools like Majestic. I suspect Moz simply hasn't collected enough meaningful data on your site yet.

Comment: Thanks! I just expected that it would at least be more than one (two or something), but obviously I was wrong! The only thing is, how come it ranks alright in Google then? Because I know a few weeks ago it didn't, and the authority hasn't increased at all since then

Comment: Things can and do rank in Google despite having few external links. Much depends on the search terms used, and how competitive they are: "code the web" is basically your brand term, so you'd expect to rank well for it. But how well do you rank for a generic term, like "the complete guide to HTML icons"? Not very well, despite being a low-competition term that matches one of your article titles. Also bear in mind that PA and DA are Moz's own metrics, not Google's, and do not necessarily correlate with ranking (in fact they very often don't).